# How can i install windows 7 driver on windows 8?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, drivers

I cannot find a driver for my video card for Windows 8 but there are drivers for Windows 7 and Vista. I was thinking if I could somehow force the windows 7 version to install on my windows 8.

Is this possible?

Comment: why dont u try run compatablity center and run the app for desired old os?

Comment: Yes and you shouldn't even need to force it. There's no guarantee that it'll work, but the driver structure of Vista, 7 and 8 is basically the same. Chances are though that older drivers might cause problems, so rather use those for 7 instead of Vista.

Comment: No i cant install it,i've tried and it pops up saying 'this computer doesnt meet the minimum requirements for installing this software'

Comment: @Vignesh4303-Thanks,but i am not familiar with what you said.Can you explain the process?

Comment: It is possible but not 100% guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

This Might Be an option to run any old programs but **with respect to driver softwares there might be some issues on softwares functionality**

1. Select whatever the `exe` which you wish to run
2. Rightclick the `exe` navigate to `properties`
3. Choose `Compatablity mode` and check the `select the Run This Program in Compatibility Mode For check box.`

[image]

choose the `os` and `run the program`

According to microsoft the PCA can be used for these things :

```
App fails to Install or Uninstall
App fails to run with a Windows version check message
App fails to launch due to administrative privilege
App crashes due to specific memory problems
App fails due to mismatched system files
App fails due to Unhandled Errors on 64-bit Windows
App fails while attempting to delete protected non-Windows files
App fails while attempting to modify Windows files
App fails due to using 8- or 16-bit color modes
App fails due to graphics and display issues
App fails to declare DPI awareness
App fails due to missing Windows features
App fails due to unsigned drivers on 64-bit Windows 8
Tracking apps installed through compatibility settings
App fails to launch installers or updaters
App installers that need to run with administrative privilege
Legacy Control Panel applets that need to run with administrative privilege
```

**Note** : **This process is for only external softwares, There's no guarantee for motherboard drivers that it'll work**

Comment: I have tried that before and it doesn't help.

Comment: Compatibility mode is for applications, not system components.  A driver is not an application so the mode doesn't apply.

Comment: @ssj does driver malfunction?or the setup itself didnt run?

Comment: the setup doesn't run it comes up with a pop up in the middle saying 'this computer doesnt meet the minimum requirements for installing this software'

Comment: @Bill-yea,makes sense.

Comment: You still have several other possibilities: 1. Use a generic driver from the video chipset manufacturer not the one by your card vendor. 2. Try to find a modded generic driver. This one might install without complaining. 3. Extract the setup files if possible and install the driver manually. 4. Install the driver on Windows 7 and extract the necessary files manually from the system and then install them on 8. May be, just may be you should state your graphics card brand and model.

Comment: @Bill Driver installers are applications though. One "feature" of installers is to check whether the user runs the setup on a supported operating system. There's a good chance that newer driver installers error out telling the user that their system is not supported. In those cases, the answer Vignesh gave is a valid solution. You are right though for the drivers themselves. Those can't operate in different compatibility modes which is probably why you can't set them for them in Windows.